# How to flush mock fn calls?

Tags: redux, jestjs

*tl;dr* Not toHaveBeenCalled gives me an error because the previous test called this function.

I am trying to unit test my reducer function.

```
function reducer(previousState, action) {
  const { type } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case '1':
      return {};
    case '2':
      return {};
    default:
      if (!type.startsWith('@@redux')) console.error(`Action type: '${type}' has no corresponding reducer.`);
      return previousState;
  }
}
```

I mock console.error

```
let consoleErrorSpy;
beforeAll(() => {
  consoleErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(global.console, 'error')
    .mockImplementation(jest.fn); // mute console errors
});
```

I test console.error

```
 it('should print a console error if unknown action was given', () => {
    reducer({}, { type: 'unknown' });
    expect(consoleErrorSpy.mock.calls[0][0])
      .toBe(`Action type: 'unknown' has no corresponding reducer.`);
  });
```

And immediately after that, I test the if case

```
  it('should not print a console error, if action came from redux internals', () => {
    reducer({}, { type: '@@redux/INTERNAL_ACTION' });
    expect(consoleErrorSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

But I get this error "Expected mock function not to be called but it was called with: ["Action type: 'unknown' has no corresponding reducer."]"

Which comes from the previous test.
Can I flush calls of a function before making the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your mock before each test :

```
consoleErrorSpy.mockClear()
```

More on that in [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockreset).

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was searching for.